# XI52 IBM Websphere DataPower

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have a service like this
MPGW <===> WSP <===> Backend

On the response, I have an attachment which I was expecting the type to be 'XOP' but instead I'm getting 'MIME'  . Is there any way I can over ride to XOP?

FYI...when I hit the service directly the back-end (by passing datapower), I'm getting XOP attachment type.

Comment: Are you talking about the response you see in the MPGW or already in the WSP?

Answer (score 0):

Processing MTOM with SOAP 1.1 is not supported in DataPower so make sure you are using SOAP 1.2.

You need to check if it is the WSP (likely) or the MPGW that is changing the response. This you can do using the Probe.

You can handle the attachments in a MTOM Policy for the service. Also use pass-through if possible for the MPGW to make sure it is not changing the payload.